# Sorting a second List by the order of another

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app, which acts as an address book. I want to sort the 'names' list alphabetical and sort the addresses list, matching to the sorting of the names, to implement them into a listview. How can I archive this sorting of the second one?

```
void main() {
    List<String> names = ["Charles","Kevin","George"]
    List<String> adresses = ["Western Street 2","Roundabout 4","Western Street 4"]
    List<String> sortedNames = sortNames(names);
}

List<String> sortNames(List<String> names) {
    return names..sort((String a, String b)=>a.compareTo(b));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically possible, but it will be more headache than it's worth. Trying to juggle two lists and ensure that their orders always line up is just asking for convoluted code and complicated bugs.

If the data in both lists is related and there is a one-to-one relationship between them, then bundle the data into data objects and have a single list of those.

(Also, there's a much easier way to sort a list.)

```dart
class Person {
  Person(this.name, this.address);

  String name;
  String address;
}

void main() {
  List<Person> persons = [
    Person('Charles', 'Western Street 2'), 
    Person('Kevin', 'Roundabout 4'),
    Person('George', 'Western Street 4'),
  ];

  // This approach sorts the list in place, changing the order of the original list
  persons.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));

  // This approach returns a new list, leaving the original unaffected
  final sortedPersons = List.of(persons)..sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I already coded 1 hour on an algorithm that finds a pattern in the sorting and uses it on the second one. It was working fine but had a bug, related to the fact that I was changing the original list, so your variant of sorting just fixed it. Thanks a lot!